# Finding a vector orthogonal to another invoking only coordinate free operations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

Assume I give you 2 vectors $u, v$, you don't know their coordinates nor their dimension, you know they are not orthogonal and not co linear, you also know both have a norm of 1.

You want to construct a vector $w$ such that $w$ is orthogonal to $u$ and is contained in the span of $u, v$. You may use any dimension independent operations, e.e.g normalization is allowed, the dot product is allowed, but the cross product is not.

I have the following:

We know that by the assumption $u, v$ span a plane embedded in some space, thus we have $w = au + bv$ for some values of $a,u$ and we want $w \cdot u = 0$.

So:

$$(au + bv) \cdot u = au^2 + bvu = 0$$

And thus we get that:

$$\frac{a}{b} = -\frac{vu}{u^2} = \frac{\|v\|\cos(\theta)}{\| u\|}$$

Thus any pair of numbers satisfying the above ratio should suffice, then the following should be ok I think:

For $b=1$.

$$a = -\frac{vu}{u^2} $$

Does this work or did I miss something?

Comment: Please don’t use $vu$ to mean $v \cdot u$. The dot product isn’t associative, so you shouldn’t consider it as a product. Your result is fine, though it’s good practice to write the final result and then check that it has the properties you want.You didn’t use that your vectors have norm 1 to simplify your result.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is

$$\begin{align}
(au+bv)\cdot u&=0\\
a(u\cdot u)+b(v\cdot u)&=0\\
a+b\|v\|\|u\|\cos\theta&=0\\
\frac{a}{b}&=-\cos\theta
\end{align}$$

Note that: $(au+bv)\cdot u =0 \nRightarrow a\|u\|^2+b\|v\|\|u\|=0$